# ADB Update Factory Reset?

Tags: android

Nexus 6 won't OTA update a security patch (and therefore won't allow for future updates) so I'm going to have to side load via ADB update.
Will this factory reset the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Factory reset means wiping /data and /cache partitions. This is needed when flashing the device (installing new ROM for example). Sideloading on the other hand is targeted update of particular components.

As per Google, OTA binary image files that allow you to manually update your Nexus devices. This has the same effect of flashing the corresponding factory images, but without the need of wiping the device.

So short answer is No, it won't wipe /data

However, if you are afraid of losing your data perform a backup of your device (use Super Backup for example). This is a common sense so I'd recommend to do it anyway.

OTA updates are incremental. That means in one version could only be installed on top of another. Make sure that minimum build required is actually installed on your device.

To do that go to Settings > About Phone and scroll down to About Phone. Now scroll down to the bottom and look at the Build Number. Make sure it matches the “From” listed below for the device that you’re upgrading. If you didn’t receive a security update that rolled out before the Android version update you want to install, be sure to download and install that first.
(instructions are from [here](http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-install-ota-updates-on-google-nexus-devices/3/))

Comment: Further question, as I'm currently on the February patch, do I need to chronologically update patch by patch or will skipping to the latest work?

Comment: Security updates are incremental. But make sure that they are applicable to your current build.

Here's a pretty good explanation on how to handle build versions:
http://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/how-to-install-ota-updates-on-google-nexus-devices/3/

Take a look at note on Page 3